# Random Number Generation for Continuously Decrementing Range

Tags: matlab

How can I create a matrix of a size 50 x 50 in MATLAB and each column vector of matrix i.e., 50 x 1 size must have random numbers within a given range and then range for the next column vectors must decrement by k until last column vector is reached?

Answer (score 2):

A solution may be to generate two matrices:

- A 50x50 matrix containing random values between 0 and 1
- A 50x50 matrix containing the upper limits for each cell

The elementwise multiplication of both matrices should give you the desired matrix.